# Trouble Connecting Neo4j Web Administration to My Data

Tags: database, neo4j, embedded-database, graph-databases, web-administration

I have loaded a bunch of data into the data base in my java application. However, when I start the Web Administration server, all I can see is the default 1 node, 1 relationship. How do I (point?) this server to the data files I specified in the EmbeddedGraphdatabase instance? I have included a snippet of code, if that helps. Thanks!

```
// The path to my data files is var/graphDb/full_abstract1. I want Web Admin to point HERE
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "var/graphDb/full_abstract1" );
registerShutdownHook(graphDb);

Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    int count = 0;
    try {
        for (org.openbel.framework.common.model.Statement s : statements) {

            firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
            String str = s.getSubject().toBELShortForm();
            firstNode.setProperty("getSubject()", str);

            secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
            String str0 = s.getObject().toBELShortForm();
            secondNode.setProperty( "getObject()", str0);

            // have to convert the Relationship Type
            org.openbel.framework.common.enums.RelationshipType r = s.getRelationshipType();
            RelationshipType r_neo = makeNeoRType(r);
            relation = firstNode.createRelationshipTo(secondNode, r_neo);

            tx.success();
            out.println("# statements: " +count++);
        }
    }
    finally {
        tx.finish();
    }
    // Some debug code, to make sure I get all the nodes I expect.
    for (Node n : graphDb.getAllNodes()) {
        for (Relationship r : n.getRelationships()) {
            out.println("Node Id: " +n.getId());
            out.println("Relationship Type: " +r.getType());
        }
    }
    out.println("Done");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You edit `conf/neo4j-server.properties` and set the database path to `var/graphDb/full_abstract1`

You can also start the web-interface as part of your java application, see: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-embedded.html

Comment: Thanks, finally got it by changing the file to point at my created database. Seems like a pain to change the config file everytime you want to see a different database though.

Comment: you can also start the web-interface as part of your java app for introspection, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-embedded.html